# Correct amount of force on piece of paper when leveling bed

Tags: print-quality, heated-bed, extrusion, adhesion

I am having some problems with bed adhesion and curling of the edges. Also my printer causes a lot of stringing when creating the first layer. This can cause the print to let go of the bed and then it just drags around with the nozzle.

I have a Anet A8 and I tried multiple different amounts of force pressing down on the paper. However, what is the desired amount of force pushing down on the paper? Is it supposed to move freely, or is it supposed to be quite hard to move around under the nozzle?

I'm using basic filament from Gearbest: [Gearbest Filament](https://www.gearbest.com/3d-printer-supplies/pp_367906.html).

[image: Perfect Nozzle Level]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual task in your case is to find correct nozzle height for the first layer, so the force for pulling out the paper is not important. It just has to be the same every time you make calibration. Because of the different force you apply, different paper thickness and other factors, found position can only be treated as 'relative'.

To complete the calibration you will have to make several test prints with different initial heights, starting from the lowest, adding 0.1-0.2mm (depending on the nozzle diameter) before you find the right value.

Please note that 1) initial layer height is not the only factor, affecting adhesion 2) some slicer programs may add not the same amount of height that you specify

Comment: I might add that, unless the OP has an automatic leveler, the test prints may adhere well in one area but not another until the bed is perfectly parallel to the X- and Y-drives.

Comment: In this case I should have added other calibration details, such as filament extrusion multiplier which also affect adhesion but not add to the clarity.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft This is the case, yesterday I leveled the bed with pretty good tension on the piece of paper. The skirt printed perfectly but in the center the PLA was not sticking to the bed, it was dragging filament arround in big stringy blobs but i left it alone and it printed pretty well. It just made the first layer pretty bad.